# Base Entity custom column

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entity, radix

i have base entity like

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    public class BaseEntityCore implements Serializable {
    
        @CreatedBy
        @Column(name = "olusturan", /* nullable = false, */ length = 50, updatable = false)
        private String createdBy;
    
        @CreatedDate
        //@NotNull
        @Column(name = "olusturma_tarihi", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        private LocalDateTime createdDate ;
    
        @LastModifiedBy
        @Column(name = "guncelleyen", length = 50)
        private String lastModifiedBy;
    
        @LastModifiedDate
        @Column(name = "guncelleme_tarihi")
        private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;
    
        @Column(name = "aktif")
        private int aktif;

// getter and setter
```

and a entity extends this base entity like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
@EntityListeners(value = { AbstractEntityListenerCore.class })
public class foo extends BaseEntityCore {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name="foo_name")
private String fooName;
//getter and setter
}
```

with spring , spring jpa. i also have entity repo like

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
Optional<Foo> findByFooName(String name);
}
```

now i can save entity with foo.setAktif(1). after saving foo i see on table aktif is 1. After that i run findByFooName method. this turns the object but this object has 2 aktif properties. first is aktif and value is 1 and the other is BaseEntityCore.aktif and value is 0. i check with if clause like

```
if(foo.getAktif()==1){
//do something
}
else {
//throws exception;
}
```

i cant get it why always throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your if else clause.
Just search always for Entities with "Aktif" == 1.

So extend your repo class with an other method

```
Optional<Foo> findByFooNameAndAktif(String name, int aktif);
```

and only search for the "aktif" you want.

But your question is about the 2 properties of "Aktif" right?

Comment: actually i can change repo method and add andAktif but the issue is 2 same properties. also getAktif() returns 0 not 1. why? how can i choose the right one?